# Why is my merge sort slower than this merge sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, merge, mergesort

I've implemented merge sort in C/C++. But my code takes longer time than the code I pulled from a website.

The recursive code seems to be exactly same for both cases:

```
void mergeSort(int* arr, int l, int h) {
    if (l < h) {
        int mid = (l + h) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr,l,mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, h);
        merge(arr, l, mid, h);
    }
}
```

However the **merge** algorithm is a bit different, but I don't see any significant difference here.

**My merge algorithm** :

```
void merge(int *arr, int l, int mid, int h) {
    int i = l, j = mid+1, k = l;
    int* newSorted = new int[h+1]();
    while (i <= mid && j <= h) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[j])
            newSorted[k++] = arr[i++];
        else
            newSorted[k++] = arr[j++];
    }
    for (; i <= mid; i++)
        newSorted[k++] = arr[i];
    for (; j <= h; j++)
        newSorted[k++] = arr[j];
    k = 0;
    for (int x = l; x <= h; x++)
        arr[x] = newSorted[x];
    delete[] newSorted;
}
```

**Time taken for 200000 (two hundred thousand inputs) :**

[17 Seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OThQJ.png)

**Merge Algorithm from a website :**

```
void merge(int arr[], int p, int q, int r) {

    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;

    int* L = new int[n1];
    int *M = new int[n2];
    

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[p + i];
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        M[j] = arr[q + 1 + j];


    int i, j, k;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = p;

    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= M[j]) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            arr[k] = M[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }


    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k] = M[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    delete[] L;
    delete[] M;
}
```

**Time taken for 200000 (two hundred thousand inputs) :**

[0 Seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcuT5.png)

There is a massive difference in time. I don't understand the problem in my code. I would really appreciate if someone can help me figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: Timing c++ is tricky, are you sure the second version was not optimized away? Try measuring in [quickbench](https://quick-bench.com/).

Comment: The "website algorithm" doesn't take `0` s, it takes `0` μs. So yeah, there's definitely something wrong with the way time is measured there.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thank you very much. This solved it. Its just the algorithm is very deep and tricky and I got lost tracing it. Iam college freshman and just started learning DSA. Oh and also yes, I used only C++ and I'll stick with it :).

Comment: @JardelLucca the website is https://www.programiz.com/dsa/merge-sort.

Comment: Side note. You are measuring performances on *Debug* builds. Don't do that: for reliable timings, always measure *Release* builds. Also, since time values seems to be integers, don't use `time` function for that, but the high resolution timing from `std::chrono`.

Comment: @prapin noted .

Comment: It will be significantly faster to do a one time allocation of a working array in an entry function, then include a pointer to that array in the input parameters for the actual merge sort functions, and when done, free that one time allocated array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm need to allocate [h+1] for each step.

The algorithm from a website only need to allocate [r-p+1]
(your h = its r, your l = its p)